# Unable to run selenium webdriver scripts even after all the jars installed

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am unable to run selenium webdriver scripts on pc. I have all the necessary jar files and java installed on my pc but still I am getting just too many errors.I have attached the build path and errors in links below.

Here is the code:-

```
package Webdriver;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;


public class firstscript {
    public static void main(String args[])  {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\gkuma218\\Downloads");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        String baseurl="https://stage-portal.uhcglobal.com/testMyUHC/generate-open-token.html";
        driver.get(baseurl);
        driver.findElement(By.id("txteeid")).sendKeys("00000907777");
        driver.findElement(By.id("txtdob")).sendKeys("19920828");
        driver.findElement(By.id("txtfirstname")).sendKeys("Sanette");
        driver.findElement(By.id("txtlastname")).sendKeys("ABATE");
        driver.findElement(By.id("txtgroupid")).sendKeys("0742631");
        driver.findElement(By.id("btnSubmit")).click();

    }   
}
```

Here are the errors:-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2euR.png

Here is the build path:-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5692.png

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a classic case of [Cyclic redundancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check).

Solution:

- Either you rename the project name as *seleniumTests* and module name as *webdriverTests*
- Or you may like to create a new project with a unique name excluding the keywords **selenium** and **webdriver**.

Comment: No i have tried changing the name still its useless